# Einstein needed to think carefully about collisions

Tags: special-relativity, energy, collision, mass-energy

I was reading Wikipedia article on *Mass–energy equivalence*. I accessed an old revision of the article, from 24 August 2020, [https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Mass–energy_equivalence&oldid=974691103#Mass–velocity_relationship](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Mass%E2%80%93energy_equivalence&oldid=974691103#Mass%E2%80%93velocity_relationship)

Under the section *Mass–velocity relationship*, it says:

> Einstein wanted to omit the unnatural second term on the right-hand
> side, whose only purpose is to make the energy at rest zero, and to
> declare that the particle has a total energy, which obeys:
>
> $$E=mc^{2}$$ which is a sum of the rest energy $m_{o}c^{2}$ and the
> kinetic energy. This total energy is mathematically more elegant, and
> fits better with the momentum in relativity. But to come to this
> conclusion, Einstein needed to think carefully about collisions. This
> expression for the energy implied that matter at rest has a huge
> amount of energy, and it is not clear whether this energy is
> physically real, or just a mathematical artifact with no physical
> meaning.
>
> In a collision process where all the rest-masses are the same at the
> beginning as at the end, either expression for the energy is
> conserved. The two expressions only differ by a constant that is the
> same at the beginning and at the end of the collision. Still, by
> analyzing the situation where particles are thrown off a heavy central
> particle, it is easy to see that the inertia of the central particle
> is reduced by the total energy emitted. This allowed Einstein to
> conclude that the inertia of a heavy particle is increased or
> diminished according to the energy it absorbs or emits.

You can also check [this capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FB9vI.jpg) of the section. I do not understand the highlighted parts.

Why did Einstein need to think about collisions to conclude that the rest energy $m_{o}c^{2}$ is real and is not just a mathematical artifact?

Are they talking about matter particles, "*Still, by analyzing the situation where **particles** are thrown off a **heavy central particle**, it is easy to see that the inertia of the **central particle** is reduced by the total energy emitted*"?

Where can I find the source for this information since Wikipedia doesn't cite this source?

Please note that this is a follow-up query to a question I asked earlier: [Einstein wanted to omit the unnatural second term on the right-hand side](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/576070/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don’t think that the wording is good. I think “Einstein needed …” implies that there is no other possible way that he could have arrived at that conclusion. I do not think that is true as I have never seen a uniqueness proof for a derivation.

However, although I disagree that Einstein needed to consider collisions, it is clear that he in fact did consider collisions. In 1905 he wrote an exceptionally short paper (almost more of a long homework problem than a paper) called “Does the inertia of a body depend upon its energy content?”

In this paper, his central calculation is based on a massive object emitting two photons of equal energy and opposite momentum in the rest frame of the object. This is exactly a perfectly plastic collision in reverse.

https://www.fourmilab.ch/etexts/einstein/E_mc2/e_mc2.pdf

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I need to think about it carefully and let you know if I've any more follow up query(ies).